# Can you add parameters to Django custom admin actions?

Tags: python, django, admin, models

For example (not the case, but just to illustrate) if I wanted to add an action to set a specific field in the selected items to X. Is it possible to add an action to allow X to be entered as opposed to hard coded?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

See: [Actions that Provide Intermediate Pages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#actions-that-provide-intermediate-pages)

You can't do it right from the changelist page, but on your intermediate page, you could have a form that would allow the user to enter a value, and then use that value for the action.

Answer (score 15):

It is possible with Django 1.5, though its a little hackish. I am not sure with what other older Django versions it's possible.

You write your own ModelAdmin subclass. ModelAdmin has an attribute called `action_form` which determines the form shown before `Go` button on changelist page. You can write your own form, and set it as action_form on your ModelAdmin subclass.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.admin.helpers import ActionForm
# ActionForm is the default form used by Django
# You can extend this class

class XForm(ActionForm):
    x_field = forms.CharField()
    

class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    action_form = XForm
```

With these changes, you will have a `CharField`, where you can put value for `X`.

And use `x_field` in your action function.

```
def set_x_on_objects(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for obj in queryset:
        obj.something = request.POST['x_field']
    # do whatever else you want

class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    action_form = XForm
    actions = [set_x_on_objects]
```

Comment: to use this 

<pre> from django import forms </pre>
should be used

Comment: Works for Django 2.2. Thanks :)

Comment: Should be marked as the answer. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: This works in Django 4.0.1, but breaks delete function

Comment: The action form applies to all actions, not good.

Comment: thx. I would ideally prefer to have action for each action which different in nature. Looks like we can have only one action form